# transform the image/mask pairs into tfrecord

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, image-segmentation

With respect to the data format given by [Carvana Image Masking Challenge](https://www.kaggle.com/c/carvana-image-masking-challenge), how can we transform it to the `tfrecord` format that can be feed into the [Deeplab V3](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/deeplab) model, which can support `VOC` and `Cityscape`, which usually have mask annotation files in XML/text format.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the Carvana dataset but maybe [this link](https://medium.com/@WuStangDan/step-by-step-tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial-part-2-converting-dataset-to-tfrecord-47f24be9248d) will help you create a TFRecords file.

Comment: This does not show how to write tfrecords for masks with paths